# Degrade with Ubuntu 22.04 while printing

Tags: 22.04

With latest ubuntu 22.04 jobs are printing with default PageSize as "Letter"
irrespective of the job document size(A3/A4/11x17...)

Ubuntu 20.04:Same job when printed from 20.04 honors document size of the job(A3/A4).

LPR behaviour: Take a PDF document of size(A3/A4/11x17...) and print using "LPR" command.
e.g.: lpr -P  ~/Desktop/3Pages_A3_Landscape.pdf

OBSERVATIONS:
Ubuntu 20.04:The job is printed with size A3.
Ubuntu 22.04:The job is printed with size Letter(PPD Default).

is it degrade in Ubuntu 22.04 against 20.04 ?

Comment: What is the printer? You can always set paper size in printer settings.

Comment: But input Document Size should honor right in 20.04 i am not setting any paper size but it is honoring input document size

Answer (score 0):

With the printer switched on go to `Settings → Printers` and your printer should be listed. Click on the settings icon alongside the printer and select `Printing Options` and set the `Media Size` in the dialogue box to that which is required by selecting from the drop down options.

[image]

Comment: If i am using "lpr"  command to print jobs what will it take as default document size from PPD or how it will be

Comment: Beacuse with same(lpr) command with same ppd i am seeing different output's in different versions of ubuntu(20.04 and 22.04)

Comment: Follwoing is the command i am using to print jobs

"lpr -P Test_22_04  ~/Desktop/3Pages_A3_Landscape.pdf"

Comment: In ubuntu 20.04 output of printed with A3 but in ubuntu 22.04 output is printed with Lettter